# у него есть чемодан - by him is a suitcase

Tags: перевод

Being near something means to have it. у него есть чемодан - by him is a suitcase.
Are there other examples of Russian thinking, that can help me learn the language?

More examples I discovered:

English thinking -                                           Russian thinking

English: "On the one hand I think..., on the other hand, I think..."
Russian: "On the one side..., on the other side..."

English: "We go to the county-side..."
Russian: "We go to nature..."     (Мы идем к природе)

English: "in my opinion"
Russian: "as for me"

English: "my pleasure; you're welcome; no problem"
Russian: "please"

English: "I feel great"
Russian: "I feel myself great"

Comment: I strongly doubt it's "Russian thinking", many other languages like Turkic or Semitic ones have the same construction for 'X has Y'. It's a mere construction, just the same way as the English 'there is an X' hardly reflects the "English thinking". To learn a language one has nothing else to do but to learn the language, the understanding comes much later, when one knows really many language structures together with their diachronic development.

Comment: @YellowSky: Although there is an undeniable validity to your statement above, as a Russian learner I know where Johan is coming from. When I go to say or write something in Russian, I have to formulate it with "Russian eyes" because semantically and lexically, Russians approach things differently. The use of у+genitive is just one example, and an easy one to learn. However, in the case of уже, for example, I had to teach myself to insert it in situations where we don't use it in English normally, so that it would come naturally in Russian. I think this is what Johan is referring to.

Comment: @CocoPop - You describe what I called 'language structures'. While learning Russian you learn to structure your speech (or call it structure the situations you talk about) in a way different from what you use in your mother tongue, but that doesn't necessarily mean you've got to acquire a completely new and _integral_ way of thinking which can be called "Russian thinking", it's just like acquiring a _new habit_. If you're right-handed and learn to write with your left hand, you simply get a new habit, there's no particular philosophy or way of thinking behind it. That's what I mean.

Comment: Speaking from personal experience - learning English - nothing helped as much as listening to radio. Not watching TV, mind you, as the latter presents more distractions from the language itself.

Comment: @Alex, absolutely! I listen to horoshee.fm all the time and learned the meaning of настроения. Before, I listened to Radio Borneo, but now I get the message "Sadly it's out of our reach." Can you recommend one?

Comment: Re edits: "мы идем к природе" is bad Russian. It's *на природу* if that's how you choose to say at all, but it's much, much more common to say *за город* "out of town". 

I don't know where you get "as for me" for "in my opinion". It's not what *по-моему* means.

So right now you have a bunch of vague and partially incorrect examples of "differences in thinking"; my guess is you'll naturally feel much less motivated to seek them out as you progress in Russian.

Comment: I don't want to be the killjoy here, though — those differences in formulating things are certainly very interesting in their own right; I, too, like to note them in every language, and as a small-time conlanger, I try to come up with some entirely new phraseology — for example, the wind "flying" instead of blowing. I'm just trying to say that it ought to be taken lightly.

Comment: No, you're no killjoy here. I understand that I should not be doing this, but I really struggle getting to grips with the prepositions and utterings like "Так вот оно что!" I can't help trying to dissect phrases like these in order to understand their meaning. What must I do?

Comment: With phrases like that, it's perhaps good to keep in mind that they're greater than the sum of their parts — while those parts *mostly* add up to a construction that can be analysed and understood logically, people don't mentally go over those literal meanings when they use the phrases. I can see how it's far from obvious that *Так вот оно что!* is literally "So that's what it is!", but then there's another level, realising that it's just your basic "Oh I see", with no particular culturally unique undertones attached.

Comment: @Johan Not really, but thanks for asking though
I've had enough of it back in my soviet days :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generally, what can help you learn a language is something that's largely the opposite; not reading too much into its grammar and idiomatics. And in this particular example, "being near something means to have it" is not even the correct literal interpretation.

The *у* of *у него есть* can only roughly be translated as "by"; it's not quite the same *у*  that denotes spatial proximity. What I mean is: consider *John chopped wood with his axe* vs. *John chopped wood with his father*. The latter can be rephrased as *John and his father chopped wood [together]*; with the former, you can only do that as a joke. In the same way, there are usages of *у* that can be replaced with a synonymous preposition, *возле*, and there are those that cannot. Thus *У реки есть гостиница* "there is a hotel by the river" and *У реки есть приток* "the river has a tributary" may look grammatically the same, but they're intuitively different to a Russian speaker, and the test is that you can also say *Возле реки есть гостиница* while saying **Возле реки есть приток* would be a case of "John and his axe chopping wood together". Just like English has, as it were, a separate *with* denoting instrumentality (which is a usage of "with" that doesn't exist in Russian), so does Russian have a separate *у* denoting ownership.

You could argue, of course, that there must have been an earlier stage when this usage of *у* hadn't yet been grammaticalised, and so one *did* speak of "having" something in terms of "being near" something. But here's the tricky thing about *у*: it's slightly narrower in meaning than *возле*, in that it can only express proximity to something that is, for all practical purposes, completely immovable; a part of the fixed scenery of life. Thus when applied to a person, it would mean something like the French *chez* — "at X's place", which was presumably then generalised to mean "in the domain of X's possessions".

By the way, the verb "to have" is itself a late invention in Indo-European languages. PIE itself is believed to have expressed ownership in a manner more similar to modern Russian, but using the dative: thus in Schleicher's fable, we have **h₂áu̯ei̯ h₁i̯osméi̯ h₂u̯l̥h₁náh₂ né h₁ést* — literally "a sheep, to whom wool was not" — meaning "a sheep that had no wool". The English *have* and the (surprisingly unrelated) Latin *habeō* both started out as verbs for taking; Spanish even went through this shift once more — relegating *haber* to a purely auxiliary function and adopting *tener*, originally "to hold", as the verb for actual "having". But, as the song goes, to have is not to hold; and in the case of Russian, to be near something is not to have it.

Comment: +1, a very good answer!

Comment: That answer can be framed and hung on a wall :) Bravo!

Comment: Thank you Nikolay Ershov for your most interesting response! Tim Doner in a TED talk on YouTube say, when you say thank you in Farsi (Persian), the response may be "May I sacrifice my life for you." I don't know where this is coming from, but I was hoping that some Russian examples could bring me closer to understanding the Russian mindset and perhaps help me to construct my own sentences easier. As another example, there is also the English "on board", "above board", and other phrases that remind me of a seafaring context. Thanks again for understanding where I'm coming from!

Comment: @Johan, well, the Russian for "thank you" is a contraction of "may God deliver [you]" and I remember reading about some American politician during the Cold War wondering if it didn't say something about how deep religion was entrenched in the Russian psyche despite all the official Soviet atheism. To which I say, not necessarily. Things like that make fun linguistic trivia but don't really tell you a lot, because language in its everyday use is both very careless and "automatic" *and* has a predilection for metaphors and overstatement essentially for their own sake.

Comment: @NikolayErshov it's rather "may the God *save* you": http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE

Comment: @Hardex: *and lead us not into temptation, but deliver us from evil* — Matthew 6:13

Comment: Much as I admire Nikolay's answer - don't things like *walk up and down the street* vs. *ходить взад-вперёд по улице* indeed signify certain peculiarities of national (linguistic) thinking? There are also *down there/up here* (or vice versa), *downtown*, *upstate*... I can go on all day.